# Map values of nested objects to mui data grid react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having trouble mapping the values of the nested objects to an mui data grid. Can anyone help show me the best way to accomplish this? I made quite a few attempts to accomplish but couldn't seem to get it to populate the table. Below is the latest code I tried. I tried logging the output of the variables to the console to view the data as it was being mapped but I couldn't seem to get the values of the Events array objects to map to the data grid.

```
const nationwidePopoverRows = responseData.map((events, i) => {
    return events.Events[i].map((ti) => {
        seating: ti.seating,
        price: ti.price
    })
  })

const nationWidePopoverColumns = [
    {field: 'seating', headerName: 'SEATING LOCATION', flex: 1},
    {field: 'amountLeft', headerName: 'TICKETS LEFT', flex: 1},
    {field: 'price', headerName: 'TICKET PRICE', flex: 1},
    {field: 'url', headerName: 'BUY TICKETS', flex: 1}
  ]      

<Popover elevation={3} open={popover} anchorEl={anchorEl} onClose={handlePopoverClose} anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'bottom',horizontal: 'left'}}>
    <DataGrid 
        autoHeight
        columns={nationWidePopoverColumns}
        pageSize={15}
        rows={nationwidePopoverRows}
        getRowId={() => Math.random()}
     />
 </Popover>


[
 {
    "id": "5e7de327-f8c5-4b6e-87b3-3f5d009e52aa",
    "name": "Milwaukee Brewers",
    "event": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
    "date": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
    "arena": "American Family Field",
    "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
    "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/",
    "Events": [
        {
            "seating": "Sec TR421, Row 10",
            "amountLeft": "2 Tickets  ",
            "price": "$15.00/ea",
            "eventName": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
            "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
            "arena": "American Family Field",
            "eventDateTime": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
            "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/"
        },
        {
            "seating": "Sec 416, Row 13",
            "amountLeft": "2 or 4 Tickets  ",
            "price": "$15.00/ea",
            "eventName": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
            "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
            "arena": "American Family Field",
            "eventDateTime": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
            "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/"
        },
        {
            "seating": "Sec TB 412, Row 3",
            "amountLeft": "1 - 8 Tickets  ",
            "price": "$15.00/ea",
            "eventName": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
            "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
            "arena": "American Family Field",
            "eventDateTime": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
            "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/"
        },
        {
            "seating": "Sec TB 414, Row 3",
            "amountLeft": "1 - 5 Tickets  ",
            "price": "$15.00/ea",
            "eventName": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
            "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
            "arena": "American Family Field",
            "eventDateTime": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
            "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/"
        },
        {
            "seating": "Sec TB 411, Row 2",
            "amountLeft": "1 - 8 Tickets  ",
            "price": "$15.00/ea",
            "eventName": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
            "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
            "arena": "American Family Field",
            "eventDateTime": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
            "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/"
        },
        {
            "seating": "Sec TB 412, Row 3",
            "amountLeft": "1 - 5 Tickets  ",
            "price": "$15.00/ea",
            "eventName": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
            "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
            "arena": "American Family Field",
            "eventDateTime": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
            "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/"
        },
        {
            "seating": "Sec 415, Row 9",
            "amountLeft": "2 Tickets  ",
            "price": "$16.00/ea",
            "eventName": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
            "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
            "arena": "American Family Field",
            "eventDateTime": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
            "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/"
        },
        {
            "seating": "Sec 416, Row 15",
            "amountLeft": "2 or 4 Tickets  ",
            "price": "$16.00/ea",
            "eventName": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
            "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
            "arena": "American Family Field",
            "eventDateTime": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
            "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/"
        },
        {
            "seating": "Sec 427, Row 13",
            "amountLeft": "2 or 4 Tickets  ",
            "price": "$16.00/ea",
            "eventName": "St Louis Cardinals at Milwaukee Brewers",
            "location": "Milwaukee, WI",
            "arena": "American Family Field",
            "eventDateTime": "Tue, June 21, 2022 - 7:10 PM",
            "url": "https://nationwidetickets.com/sports/mlb/milwaukee-brewers-tickets/20220621-1910-61856357/"
        }

    ]
    },

    {
      ... more objects
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

Comment: We‘d probably have to see the components code to tell you why your table doesn‘t get populated.

Comment: I updated the question but the component isn't super relevant to the question. I can get data into the table. I just can't get the right data in there.

Comment: can you share your code in codesandbox, it will be easier to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

The way you generate rows is strange because you have a map into another one

```
const nationwidePopoverRows = responseData.map((events, i) => {
    return events.Events[i].map((ti) => {
        seating: ti.seating,
        price: ti.price
    })
  })
```

So you probably have nested arrays wherase the data grid assumes `rows` is an array of objects

Either use flatMap or other technic to get an array of object